# C++ Templates - Different Specialization for Floating and Integral types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization

I am trying to write a function with a signature like so:

```
template<typename From, typename To>
To bar(From in){...}
```

This function needs to have different behavior depending on if `To` is a floating type or a integral type. (assuming that `From` is integral and both are arithmetic)

This could be achieved easily using an `if constexpr(std::is_integral<To>::value) {...} else {...}`, however I am limited to C++11 which does not have `if constexpr`.

What is a good way to implement such a specialization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use template overloads with [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae). e.g.

```
template<typename To, typename From>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<To>::value, To>::type bar(From in) {
    ...
}

template<typename To, typename From>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<To>::value, To>::type bar(From in) {
    ...
}
```

BTW I suggest to change the declaration order of the template parameter `From` and `To`, then you can just specify the 1st template argument explicitly when calling them. Such as `bar<int>(...);` and `bar<float>(...);`.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vDKC3JymZv8jGpO7)

If you want to get a more clear message for types other than integral and float point types, you can add another overload. e.g.

```
template<class T> struct dependent_false : std::false_type {};

template<typename To, typename From>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<To>::value && !std::is_floating_point<To>::value, To>::type bar(From in) {
    static_assert(dependent_false<To>::value, "Types must be integral or floating point types.");
}
```

Comment: This is actually something I tried, however, I didn't like the fact that something invalid (eg. bar("Hello, world!", 6)) gives a cryptic error. Is there a way I could implement a better compiler error? Sadly `template<typename To, typename From> To bar(From) = delete` doesn't work :(

Comment: Also, good idea with switching the order of the Template Params! I guess I should put more thought into the order of them.

Comment: @Fuzzyzilla You have to get it out of the overload set. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that the `To` type is integral or float, another possible solution is the use of tag-dispatching

Using the fact that `std::is_integral<T>` inherit from `std::true_type`, when `T` is an integral type, or from `std::false_type`, otherwise, you can write `bar()` (using also the `From`/`To` order change suggested by songyuanyao) as follows

```
template <typename To, typename From>
To bar (From inVal)
 { return foo<To>(inVal, std::is_integral<To>{}); }
```

and develop two `foo()` template functions with different signatures (`std::true_type` or `std::false_type` for second paramenter) as follows

```
template <typename To, typename From>
To foo (From inVal, std::true_type const &)
 { std::cout << "foo() integral case: " << inVal << std::endl; return {0}; }

template <typename To, typename From>
To foo (From inVal, std::false_type const &)
 { std::cout << "foo() float case: " << inVal << std::endl; return {1}; }
```

Now, calling

```
bar<int>("abc");
bar<double>("xyz");
```

you get

```
foo() integral case: abc
foo() float case: xyz
```